# Cross-platform and language (de)serialization

Tags: language-agnostic, serialization, cross-platform

I'm looking for a way to serialize a bunch of C++ structs in the most convenient way so that the serialization is portable across C++ and Java (at a minimum) and across 32bit/64bit, big/little endian platforms.  The structures to be serialized just contain data, i.e. they're pure data objects with no state or behavior.

The idea being that we serialize the structs into an octet blob that we can store in a database "generically" and be read out later on.  Thus avoiding changing the database whenever a struct changes and also avoiding assigning each data member to a field - i.e. we only want one table to hold everything "generically" as a binary blob.  This should make less work for developers and require less changes when structures change.

I've looked at boost.serialize but don't think there's a way to enable compatibility with Java.  And likewise for inheriting Serializable in Java.

If there is a way to do it by starting with an IDL file that would be best as we already have IDL files that describe the structures.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Look at http://msgpack.org/ it is cross-platform and multi-language.

Answer (score 9):

I stumbled here, having a very similar question. 6 years later, this might not be useful to you, but hopefully it will be to others.

There are a lot of alternatives, unfortunately with no clear winner (although one could argue that JSON is the clear winner). Even Google has released multiple competing technologies (all of them apparently being used internally):

- [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/): this one seems to meet the requirements from the original question, [has interesting benchmarks](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__benchmarks.html) and [supports some form of IDL](http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__schemas.html) (I'm personally not familiar with IDL)
- [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/): mentioned previously.
- [XFJSON](https://github.com/mainroach/compression/tree/master/xfjson): 5%-12% smaller than JSON.

Not to forget the alternatives posted in the other answers. Here are a few more:

- [YAML](http://yaml.org/): JSON minus all the double quotes, but using indentation instead. It's more human readable, but probably less efficient, especially as it gets larger.
- [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) (Binary JSON)
- [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) (Another compacted JSON)

With so many variations, JSON is clearly the winner in terms of simplicity/convenience and cross-platform access. It has gained even more popularity in the last couple years, with the rise of JavaScript. A lot of people probably use that as a de-facto solution, without giving it much thought (that's what I originally did :P).

However, if size becomes an issue, but you prefer to keep things simple and not use one of the more advanced libraries, you could just compress JSON using [`zlib`](http://zlib.net/) (that's what I'm doing now), or some other cross-platform algorithm (but that's a whole other topic).

To speed up JSON handling in C++, you could also use [RapidJSON](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson).

Comment: Note that compression will save you space & bandwidth, [but will cost you in terms of performance](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/05/entry_263.html).

Answer (score 8):

If I want to go really really cross language, I normally would suggest JSON, as the ease of javascript support and an [abundance of libraries](http://www.json.org/), as well as being human readable and modifiable (I prefer it to XML as I find it smaller in terms of chars, faster, and more readable). It's not the most efficient in terms of space, however, and a more machine readable format like [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) would have advantages there (thrift can be made from an IDL, but it is also made for encoding services, so it could be heavier than you want).

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised Jon Skeet hasn't already pounced on this one :-)

[Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) is pretty much designed for this sort of scenario -- passing structured data cross-language.

That said, if you're using a database the way you suggest, you really shouldn't be using a full-strength RDBMS like Oracle or SQL Server but rather a lightweight key-value store such as Berkeley DB or one of the many "cloud table" engines.

Answer (score 2):

You need [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)! (Some people refer to this as binary XML.) ASN.1 is very compact and thus ideal to transfer data between two systems. And for those who don't think this is ever used: several Internet protocols are based upon the ASN.1 model for data serialization!

Unfortunately, there aren't many libraries available for Java or C++ that will support ASN.1. I had to work with it several years ago and just couldn't find a good, free or inexpensive tool to allow support for ASN.1 in C++. At [Objective Systems](http://www.obj-sys.com/) they are selling ASN.1/XML solutions but it's extremely expensive. (The [ASN.1 compiler](http://www.obj-sys.com/asn1-compiler.shtml) for C++ and Java, that is!) It costs you an arm and a leg at least! (But then you will have a tool that you can use with only one hand...)

Comment: Nice suggestion, but anything expensive is a no-no on this project.  I'll bear it in mind though :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest saving the data with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) database. The structs can be stored as database rows in SQLite tables.

The resulting database file is binary compatible across many different platforms and can be stored as a BLOB in your main database. I believe the file size is comparable to compressed XML file with the same data, but memory usage during processing will be significantly less than XML DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Why haven't you chosen XML, as this perfectly suits your demand. Both C++ and Java allow for an easy implementation.

Furthermore, I doubt your idea of storing everything as a blob in the database, use a relational database what a database has been designed for, or switch to some object oriented database like http://www.versant.com/en_US/products/objectdatabase which supports both Java and C++.

Comment: XML and other human readable formats aren't really an option due to the amount of overhead that will create.  At present we are looking at storing 1TB of raw data to a single disk in under a day.  The significant overhead of XML will mean we can't store as much raw data as we need to.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Avro. Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633611/what-are-the-key-differences-between-apache-thrift-google-protocol-buffers-mes) question for comparison of Apache thrift, protocol buffers, mes and so on.